# Триггеры SQL, AFTER INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, триггер

Есть таблица `timetable` с 3мя полями (`id`, `time`, `user`)

```
CREATE TRIGGER addTime
AFTER INSERT ON timetable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.time = now();
END
```

Как должно работать: Вставляем запись со значениями для колонок `id`, `user`... `time` вставляется после действия `INSERT`.

Но это не работает т.к программа ругается на `AFTER INSERT`

Comment: А зачем вам именно after, конечно он не может изменить NEW потому как вызван _после_ того, как запись попала на диск. Используйте _BEFORE_ insert.

Comment: Ну как-то логичнее внести запись после события INSERT, поэтому я выбрал AFTER, а что если у меня есть запись, которая достает последнюю строку из таблицы и по некоторым полям делает какие-то преобразования? BEFORE тут никак не сработает ибо последней строчки еще не будет и он возьмет существующую предыдущую строчку. Конечно можно использовать BEFORE и NEW чтобы обратиться к полям вставляемой записи и сделать некоторые преобразования, но для меня это кажется в некоторых случаях не совсем очевидно чем AFTER NEW

Comment: ...хотя странно что после события INSERT, SQL не может обновить некоторое поле (хотя если мы туда не вставили до этого никакого значения, то о каком обновлении идет речь?) Мне непонятно ПОЧЕМУ ОН НЕ МОЖЕТ ИЗМЕНИТЬ NEW ПОСЛЕ ТОГО КАК ЗАПИСЬ ПОПАЛА НА ДИСК?

Comment: NEW означает запись в оперативной памяти, срабатывает триггер BEFORE, потом он пишет запись на диск, после этого срабатывает AFTER. Второй раз сбрасывать на диск изменения произошедшие в NEW, ну это как то совсем странно. Это как минимум +1 операция ввода-вывода, а учитывая, что в транзакционных таблицах любая запись требует как минимум 3х операций физической записи на диск, с ожиданием завершения каждой то получаем вместо 3х сразу 6. И это без учета возможной перестройки индексов и переезда записи в другой блок вследствии увеличения ее размера

Comment: А если вам нужна некая операция достающая последнюю строку, то вы вообще должны делать триггер не for each row, а на всю операцию

Comment: все понятно, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Ключевые слова `NEW` и `OLD` можно применять только в BEFORE-триггере. Корректно триггер может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER addTime
BEFORE INSERT ON timetable
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.time = NOW();
END//
```

Вы можете вызывать в AFTER-триггере операторы `UPDATE` для обновления данных, но только не в отношении текущей таблицы - MySQL не даст изменять ее. Однако, если ваша задача изменить время только одного вставляемого столбца, нет необходимости задействовать триггер, достаточно задать условие `ON UPDATE` для столбца `time` при определении таблицы `timetable`

```
CREATE TABLE timetable (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  ...
  `time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Такой столбец можно не заполнять - ему автоматически будет назначаться текущее время.